# Parenthesize first character of each word

Tags: shell, unix

i want to Parenthesize first character of each word

```
$ echo "Welcome To The Geek Stuff" | sed 's/\(\b[A-Z]\)/\(\1\)/g'
```

can anyone explain? i am not getting how it is working?

Comment: Please note how Glen has included the error messages produced. When you write your next Q, please include 1) sample input (good, done!), 2) expected output , 3) your attempt to solve the problem (good, done!) 4) current output and error messages , 5) your thoughts (hmm, well maybe ;-) ). Glad you have a solution (I didn't downvote) . Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's/pattern1/pattern2'  --- Does "replace first occurrence of pattern1 with pattern2"

sed 's/pattern1/pattern2/g' --- Does "A (g)lobal replacement => replace all the occurrence of pattern1 with pattern2 "

sed 's/\b(pattern1)/pattern2/g'  --- Does  " A word by word search"

sed 's/\b([A-Z])/pattern2/g'  --- Does " Matches a single uppercase letter"
sed 's/\b([A-Z])/(\1)/g'     --- Does " sed 's/\b([A-Z])/([A-Z])/g' "
                                \1 is a back reference. [Refer][https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html]
```

In short It does a global replacement (replace all occurrences) of any uppercase letter with (uppercase letter) doing a word by word search.

Comment: hey what's the significance of "(\1)" here? i didn't get it?

Comment: BTW, the readers can refer to this [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html#BRE-vs-ERE) for the difference between parentheses in Basic and Extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I need to use `sed -E` to get that working.

```
$ echo "Welcome To The Geek Stuff" | sed 's/(\b[A-Z])/(\1)/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
$ echo "Welcome To The Geek Stuff" | sed -E 's/(\<.)/(\1)/g'
(W)elcome (T)o (T)he (G)eek (S)tuff
```

You could also use the `\<` anchor which is "start of word", where `\b` is "word boundary". Using start of word marker lets you simplify the regex to match any word character:

```
$ echo "Welcome To The Geek Stuff 123" | sed -E 's/\<./(&)/g'
(W)elcome (T)o (T)he (G)eek (S)tuff (1)23
```

Comment: "(\1)" can you explain this?

Comment: The **\1** refers to the matched item's position (the bit inside the parenthesis) in the matching part of the `sed`  substitution command (e.g.,., the `s/(...)/\1/g`).  If there were more matching clauses in the matching part of command, you'd reference them by position: **\1**, **\2**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should do this:

```
echo "Welcome To The Our Class" | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/\(\1\)/g'
```

(remove the "\b")
between the first "/" to the second, there is an expression to be replace on the expression between the second "/" to the third.
you search in the sentence a string that begin in capital letter(chr between A to Z) and add to this letter "(" before and ")" after. 1 means the first letter in a word.
the output will be :

```
(W)elcome (T)o  (T)he (O)ur (C)lass
```

Answer (score 0):

To parenthesize the first 3 letters of a word, you can use

> $ echo "the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy
> dog" | sed 's/(\b[a-Z]{1,3})/(&)/g' (the) (qui)ck (bro)wn (fox)
> (jum)ps (ove)r (a) (laz)y (dog) $